# Return value from method only alert dialog has been dismissed

Tags: android

I have to return some value from a method.
Now inside method I have opened an `AlertDialog`.

So my problem is my method returns value while `AlertDialog` is opened.
I want from method to  return String value only if dialog has been dismissed.
My code is

```
public String capture(final String uid, final String id) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(WebActivity.this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);



        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);



        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

        mCapture= new Capture(WebActivity.this);
        int isInitialised = mCapture.initialize();
        final String res = mCapture.capture(uid, id,
                image, dialog);

        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                // return response;
                scenario1Response = res;
            }
        });

        if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
            return scenario1Response;
        }
    }
```

But it is saying Add return statement. while I only want to return is dialog's OK but has been clicked

Please help me how can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code that is relevant to the question

Comment: check my code I updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog's `onDismissListener` like this:

```
alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //your logic of returning goes here             
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @NehaShukla As per java function and its return type, you will have to put a `return` statement for sure. So you can use `return ""` in that case at last.

Comment: but i have to only return if dialog has dismissed thats my need.I can not return null or empty.

Comment: @NehaShukla when is this function called? and how alert dialog can be dismissed? That will help me understanding flow and help you.

Comment: Actually when this method will be called some live data is being showing inside alert dialog and this method has to return some response based on live data which will be further used from caller of this method and caller will display alert dialog again based on value returned.

Comment: I guess function will return value only after alert dialog gets dismissed. Did you try inserting `return scenario1Response` only? @NehaShukla

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this from different approach, You dont have to return the value through function.
You can just assign the value to some global variable while dismissing the dialog and use it where you want.

```
public void capture(final String uid, final String id) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(WebActivity.this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);



        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);



        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

        mCapture= new Capture(WebActivity.this);
        int isInitialised = mCapture.initialize();
        final String res = mCapture.capture(uid, id,
                image, dialog);

        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                // return response;
                scenario1Response = res; // this can be your global variable
            }
        });


    }
```

and change where you are calling this function, eg:

```
VARIABLE myval = capture(param1, param2);
```

like this:

```
capture(param1, param2);
VARIABLE myval = scenario1Response;
```

hope you got my point..